# Use spark dataframe column value as an alias of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using spark and scala i would like to set a struct and use one of the column value as an alias of another column.

I have this dataframe

```
root
|-- type: string (nullable = true)
|-- metadata
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

And i would like to have this

```
root
|-- metadata
    |-- TYPE_VALUE
        |-- name: string (nullable = true)
        |-- age: long (nullable = true)
        |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
        |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

In my dataframe, i try with `struct($"metadata".as($"type".toString())).alias("metadata")` but its doesn't work, it take the field name instead of taking the value.

Comment: Not sure it's possible in a single pass. The schema is defined before processing so I doubt you could do it in a single processing.  Instead you could try to extract the type column, build the struct from it and transform the DataFrame. Please insert some code you use, it'll give more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is not going to work, because that would require a dynamic schema that is not known beforehand.
The best you could do is create a mapping out of it:

```scala
df.select(
  map('type, 'metadata).as("metadata")
)
```

With an output like:

```
+-------------------------------+
|metadata                       |
+-------------------------------+
|Map(type1 -> [Tom,38,M,NL])    |
|Map(type2 -> [Marijke,37,F,NL])|
+-------------------------------+

res1: Unit = ()
root
 |-- metadata: map (nullable = false)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- age: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

Or just split the data based on the `type` and process each type as separate dataframe

Comment: let me check the solution with the map. Thanks for your answer